# Stringbuffer issues

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, stringbuffer

I wrote a code that enable users to open a text file in a text area and input new characters just like a text editor.It seems like there is a capacity issue when editing a large file and inputting large amount of charcater, the file doesn't get saved.
I have tried StringBuffer stuff.ensureCapacity(10000);and still didn't work.
I wonder if the problem is when saving to a file or when modifying within my text area?
I have something like this:

```
  java.lang.StringBuffer text = new java.lang.StringBuffer();
  //some code here

  File myFile = new File(filename);
  DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream (myFile));

    while((data = dis.readLine()) != null)
    {
      text.append(data+"\n");
    }
```

Comment: could you show us code related to file writing?

Comment: I dont think that this is an capcity issue, it is more an coding issue; But we will see more, if you post the relevant code.

Comment: After I reached the 2680 caracters, I was unable to add nor delete caracters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some pointers.

- You don't need to specify `java.lang.`
- Don't use StringBuffer if you can use StringBuilder
- Most importantly, don't mix text and binary as it will lead to confusion.

If you want to read a whole file as a String I suggest using in Java 7

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("logs", "access.log");
String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), "UTF-8");
```

or with Apache Commons IO [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

```
String text = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(filename));
```

Comment: This issue only occurs when I reach about 2680 characters, after that the file is non editable, Unless a delete few characters. StringBuilder could't fix the issue, since I am coding in jsp I will try apache fileutils.

Comment: Can you provide an example which we can reproduce your problem because nothing in the code provided demonstrates this? String and StringBuffer can contain 2 billion characters

Comment: <textarea class="form-textarea resizable" cols="80" rows="50" id="textarea" name="thetext" style="width:90%;height:27em;font-family:courier;font-size:14;"><%=text.toString()%></textarea>

Comment: the problem is not with the reading is actually with the string append and saving.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the code above and could even be a browser issue?  Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: it shoudln't be a browser issue, since the file was I was able to read and save small file, but not large ones.

Comment: So I suspect it has nothing to do with the Java or JSP etc, instead it's a bug in the browser which you have to find a work around for. If it works in one browser and not another, it's a browser issue.